# Is APPCDS available in OpenJdk?

Tags: java

I see that AppCDS is listed as commerical feature in Oracke Java SE.

Does Oracle Open JDK have this feature free of cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppCDS and other JDK commercial features will be open source soon. See http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2017-September/004281.html

> After JDK 9 we'll open-source the commercial features in order to make
>   the OpenJDK builds more attractive to developers and to reduce the
>   differences between those builds and the Oracle JDK.  This will take
>   some time, but the ultimate goal is to make OpenJDK and Oracle JDK
>   builds completely interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. [From an Oracle employee on the OpenJDK mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2017-May/047412.html):

> AppCDS is an experimental (i.e can not be used in production) feature and is not available in OpenJDK

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, since OpenJDK 10, it is. See https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/310 and https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/10/